# How to sum all fields in table

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a ngFor and invoice total is calculate of price and hours
but still i want the totals of all total

```
<tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoiceItem.rows">
    <td>{{ invoice.rowName }}</td>
    <td>{{ invoice.hours}}</td>
    <td>{{ invoice.price }}</td>
    <td>{{ invoice.comments }}</td>
    <td>{{ invoice.total}} </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>total ex 18%</td>
    <td>{{ totals }}</td>
</tr>
```

and in the typescript file i have the constructor that should calculate the totals.
After many hours I think its time to ask:(

```
export class DemoTestComponent {
    public invoiceItem: ItemInvoice;
    public invoiceItem2: ItemInvoice;

    public invoices: InvoiceData;
    public invoiceRows: InvoiceDetailsRows[];
    public totals: number;
    //public theTex: number;
    //public totalsAfterTax: number;
    constructor(http: Http) {
        http.get('/api/Invoice/test/1').subscribe(result => {
            this.invoiceItem = result.json();
            this.invoiceItem.rows.forEach((item) => {
                item.total = calculate(item);
            })
            var tempnumber;
            this.invoiceItem.rows.forEach((item) => {
                tempnumber += item.total;
            })
            this.totals = tempnumber;
            //this.theTex = this.totals * 0.18;
            //this.totalsAfterTax = this.totals + this.theTex;

        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be the problem you are facing is because of you are calling this in constructor. you should call it in ngoninit. all our http request should be in lifecycle hooks not in constructor.

```
  export class DemoTestComponent {
            public invoiceItem: ItemInvoice;
            public invoiceItem2: ItemInvoice;

            public invoices: InvoiceData;
            public invoiceRows: InvoiceDetailsRows[];
            public totals: number;
            //public theTex: number;
            //public totalsAfterTax: number;
            constructor(http: Http) { }
            ngOnInit() { 
              http.get('/api/Invoice/test/1')
                    .map(result => result.json())
                    .subscribe(result => {
                    this.invoiceItem = result;
                    this.invoiceItem.rows.forEach((item) => {
                        item.total = calculate(item);
                    })
                    var tempnumber=0;
                    this.invoiceItem.rows.forEach((item) => {
                        tempnumber += item.total;
                    })
                    this.totals = tempnumber;
                    //this.theTex = this.totals * 0.18;
                    //this.totalsAfterTax = this.totals + this.theTex;
                });
             }
          }
```

are you getting any error ? if you still get any error then show your Json data. i will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialised `var tempnumber;`, therefore, it is `undefined` and will return `NaN` when you try to sum it in the loop.

Change this bit:

```
var tempnumber;
```

to

```
var tempnumber = 0;
```

And try to use `let` in block scoped variables instead of `var`.

Or with reduce

```
let tempnumber = 0;
this.invoiceItem.rows.reduce((total, current) => tempnumber = total + current, tempnumber);

this.totals = tempnumber;
```